# How to make JRuby 1.6 default to Ruby 1.9?

Tags: jruby

what is the best way to make JRuby to run in 1.9 mode by default?

i.e, I want to run `rake test` instead of `jruby --1.9 -S rake test`

Thank you

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Use the `JRUBY_OPTS` environment variable.  `JRUBY_OPTS` holds a list of arguments that are added to any arguments specified on the command line.

For example (on Linux):

```
$ jruby -v
jruby 1.6.0.RC1 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 330) (2011-01-10 769f847) (Java HotSp...
$ export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
$ jruby -v
jruby 1.6.0.RC1 (ruby 1.9.2 trunk 136) (2011-01-10 769f847) (Java HotSpot(TM...
$ export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8
$ jruby -v
jruby 1.6.0.RC1 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 330) (2011-01-10 769f847) (Java HotSpo...
```

Answer (score 22):

An alternative solution is to put the following line (and other settings) in your ~/.jrubyrc file

```
compat.version=1.9
```

Answer (score 18):

RVM allows now building JRuby/Rubinius with default mode set by default:

```
rvm install jruby-1.6.7-d19 --1.9
rvm install rbx-2.0.testing-d19 --1.9
```

The suffix `-d19` can be omitted, I use it only to distinguish between **1.8** and **1.9** mode rubies.

The `--1.9` mode will become the default in next major releases of JRuby/Rubinius, so you can make sure you will use **1.8** with `--1.8` rvm switch.

**UPDATE 2012-05-25:** Jruby 1.7.0.preview1 is out, it is 1.9 by default!

Answer (score 11):

In Windows, use
`set JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9` instead.

Answer (score 8):

When using warbler to package an app as a war file, the version can be set by running:

```
warble config
```

which creates a `config/warble.rb` file.  This file contains lots of comments on how to configure warbler, and in particular:

```
  # Set JRuby to run in 1.9 mode.
  # config.webxml.jruby.compat.version = "1.9"
```

Uncomment the second line by removing the `#`, and re-package your war with the `warble` command.

Answer (score 6):

If you're creating jruby from java:

```
RubyInstanceConfig config = new RubyInstanceConfig();   
config.setCompatVersion(CompatVersion.Ruby1_9); 
Ruby runtime = Ruby.newInstance(config)
```

(Thanks to bbrowning on the #jrubyc irc channel)