# Ruby vs JRuby: Time.new

Tags: ruby, jruby, ruby-1.9.2

I have a web app which works, for the most part with MRI Ruby and JRuby. But...

When I am using MRI, I can do this.

```
> rails console
irb(main):001:0> a=Time.new(1,1,1,1,1)
=> 0001-01-01 01:01:00 -0500
```

i.e. It creates a new Time object for the specified time.

When I switch to JRuby I do this

```
> rails console
irb(main):001:0> a=Time.new(1,1,1,1,1)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (5 for 0)
     from (irb):2: in `evaluate`
     from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1088 in `eval`
     from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158 in `eval_input`
     from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.8/
....
```

How can I create a Time object in JRuby with a year, month, day, hour, and minutes which I control? If so, can this work with MRI Ruby as well?

I don't know if this is related, but

```
irb(main):002:0> RUBY_VERSION
"1.8.7"
```

Could my problem be because I'm in 1.8.7 mode? If so, how do I switch my rbenv/jruby-1.6.4 installation to act like RUBY_VERSION=1.9.2 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755900/how-to-make-jruby-1-6-default-to-ruby-1-9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is related to the RUBY_VERSION
You need JRUBY to be in 1.9 mode.
You can set this through JRUBY_OPTS

Try this:

```
export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
```

or this (on Windows):

```
set JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
```

Example session (Windows):

```
> set JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
> jirb
irb(main):001:0> a=Time.new(1,1,1,1,1)
=> 0001-01-01 01:01:00 +0918
```