# Does JRuby support the { thing: "hello" } syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax, jruby

I'm getting a lot of syntax errors:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/davidtuite/dev/ruby/seenbefore_client/spec/lib/url_group_spec.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected ':'

      records = stub(length: length)
```

yet the [JRuby Blog](http://jruby.org/2011/02/09/jruby-1-6-0-rc2.html) says that "Compiler handles all 1.9 syntax now" since JRuby 1.6.0.rc2.

I'm using JRuby 1.6.5

```
rvm info
  ruby:
    interpreter:  "jruby"
    version:      "1.6.5"
    date:         "2011-10-25"
    platform:     "darwin-x86_64-java"
    patchlevel:   "TM"
    full_version: "jruby 1.6.5 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) (2011-10-25 9dcd388) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_29) [darwin-x86_64-java]"
```

Comment: You must [use 1.9 mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755900/how-to-make-jruby-1-6-default-to-ruby-1-9).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JRuby can be made 1.9.2-compatible by adding the `--1.9` command line switch or by adding that switch to the `JRUBY_OPTS` environment variable:

```
$ export JRUBY_OPTS='--1.9' 
$ bin/irb
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.2"
irb(main):002:0> {asd:3}
=> {:asd=>3}
```

Don't know how you can tell your RVM that, though. By the way, on Windows the batch syntax is `set JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9`.

Comment: the new jruby version will use 1.9 mode by default

Comment: @three: Thanks for the info, but the current version from the website does not.

Comment: ok, maybe this is only true for the master branch and all upcoming versions: https://twitter.com/#!/headius/status/162953097780535296

Comment: @three: That's most probably the case.

Comment: I fetched `jruby-head` with RVM and it seems to work so it woul appear that @three is correct.

Comment: @duckyfuzz no, headius is correct, after all he's the maintainer :)