# Error: mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I recently install clean ubuntu14.04 virtual machine in vware fusion and updated it. I am trying to install the mime-tyes-data by

> sudo gem install mime-types-data -v 3.2015.1120

The error shows

> ERROR:  Error installing mime-types-data:
>       mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0.

Before that I already update ruby version by

> sudo apt-get install ruby2.0
>
> sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/ruby2.0 /usr/bin/ruby

It seems my version of ruby is 2.0 already, but the error still exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was facing the same problem trying to install rails with sudo. I was getting:
 ERROR: Error installing mime-types-data: mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0.

The thing is `ruby -v` gives me ruby 2.2.1p85 while `sudo ruby -v` gives me ruby 1.9.3p484, so instead of `sudo gem install rails` I just did `gem install rails` and it worked.

That is where I found my solution: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3558

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error as others here. I was trying to install JRuby and kept getting

```
ERROR: Error installing mime-types-data: mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0
```

From this page I got that JRuby doesn't use the version of ruby you might think it does. So you can check what it's using by doing:

```
jruby -v
```

The version of Ruby is in brackets.
Then to upgrade the version of Ruby being used I got [a tip from this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755900/how-to-make-jruby-1-6-default-to-ruby-1-9) which said to add an env var:

```
set JRUBY_OPTS=--2.0
```

All working better now, well no error anymore!

Answer (score 2):

To fix, edit Gemfile

```
gem "mime-types", '2.6.2'
```

Then run in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

if that does not work, try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

as the update to `bbb-record-core` now includes the above fix

Comment: The error I described occurred when I am trying to install rails after ruby installed. Could you tell me where the Gemfile located when installing rails?

Comment: Did you create an app using `rails new APP_NAME`. If you didn't then create a new one. Then `Gemfile` will be automatically created. In the `Gemfile` add the line. Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Sorry you may misunderstood my words. I installed ruby, then want to install ruby on rails, not create an app. When I am installing rails, the error occurs shown above. I cannot successfullly install rails framework yet.

Comment: why you want to install `mime-types-data -v 3.2015.1120` before rails framework installation. First, install rails framework successfully then install `mime-types-data -v 3.2015.1120` as gem. In that case, i think you can proceed with the second and third steps. Lets see if the problem solves in your side.

Comment: I tried installingl rails framework and result is failure. The error shows : ERROR: Error installing mime-types-data: mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0. The same error shown above.

Comment: Update your dist libraries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107487/discussion-between-mohammad-shahadat-hossain-and-peterxwl).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem by downgrading from rails '4.2.6' to rails '4.1.0'.